# changing wide to long table format and splitting dates by year

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table that looks like this:

```
temp = [['K98R', 'AB',34,'2010-07-27', '2013-08-17', '2008-03-01', '2011-05-02', 44],['S33T','ES',55, '2009-07-23', '2012-03-12', '2010-09-17', '', 76]]
Data = pd.DataFrame(temp,columns=['ID','Initials','Age', 'Entry','Exit','Event1','Event2','Weight'])
```

What you see in the table above, is that there is an entry and exit dates, with dates for the events 1 and 2, there is also a missing date for event 2 for the second patient because the event didn't happen. Also note that the event1 for the first patient happened before entry date.

What I am trying to achieve is a two fold:
1. Split the time between the entry and exit into years
2. Convert the wide format to long one with one row per year
3. Check if event 1 and 2 have occurred during the time period included in each row

To explain further, here is the output I am trying to ge.

```
ID    Initial   Age   Entry       Exit     Event1   Event2 Weight
K89R    AB       34 27/07/2010  31/12/2010  1       0       44
K89R    AB       35 1/01/2011   31/12/2011  1       1       44 
K89R    AB       36 1/01/2012   31/12/2012  1       1       44
K89R    AB       37 1/01/2013   17/08/2013  1       1       44
S33T    ES       55 23/07/2009  31/12/2009  0       0       76
S33T    ES       56 1/01/2010   31/12/2010  1       0       76
S33T    ES       57 1/01/2011   31/12/2011  1       0       76
S33T    ES       58 1/01/2012   12/03/2012  1       0       76
```

What you notice here is that the entry to exit date period is split into individual rows per patient, each representing a year. The event columns are now coded as 0 (meaning the event has not yet happened) or 1 (the event happened) which is then carried over to the years after because the event has already happened.

The age increases in every row per patient as time progresses

The patient ID and initial remain the same as well as the weight.

Could anyone please help with this, thank you

Comment: Please clean your sample data. The dates have different formats and Event2 is not present.

Comment: Apologies, I have edited the dataset

Comment: Is there a maximum of two events or do you need this to work for an arbitrary number of events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Begin by getting the number of years between Entry and Exit:**

```
# Convert to datetime
df.Entry = pd.to_datetime(df.Entry)
df.Exit = pd.to_datetime(df.Exit)
df.Event1 = pd.to_datetime(df.Event1)
df.Event2 = pd.to_datetime(df.Event2)
# Round up, to include the upper years 
import math
df['Years_Between'] = (df.Exit - df.Entry).apply(lambda x: math.ceil(x.days/365))

# printing the df will provide the following:

    ID  Initials    Age Entry   Exit    Event1  Event2  Weight  Years_Between
0   K98R    AB  34  2010-07-27  2013-08-17  2008-03-01  2011-05-02  44  4
1   S33T    ES  55  2009-07-23  2012-03-12  2010-09-17  NaT 76  3
```

**Loop through your data and create a new row for each year:**

```
new_data = []

for idx, row in df.iterrows():  

  year  = row['Entry'].year
  new_entry = pd.to_datetime(year,  format='%Y')

  for y in range(row['Years_Between']):

    new_entry = new_entry + pd.DateOffset(years=1)
    new_exit = new_entry + pd.DateOffset(years=1) - pd.DateOffset(days=1)

    record = {'Entry': new_entry,'Exit':new_exit}

    if row['Entry']> new_entry:
      record['Entry'] = row['Entry']

    if row['Exit']< new_exit:
      record['Exit'] = row['Exit']

    for col in ['ID', 'Initials', 'Age', 'Event1', 'Event2', 'Weight']:
      record[col] = row[col]

    new_data.append(record)
```

**Create a new DataFrame, the compare dates:**

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns = ['ID','Initials','Age', 'Entry','Exit','Event1','Event2','Weight'])
df_new['Event1'] = (df_new.Event1 <= df_new.Exit).astype(int)
df_new['Event2'] = (df_new.Event2 <= df_new.Exit).astype(int)

# printing df_new will provide:
    ID  Initials    Age Entry   Exit    Event1  Event2  Weight
0   K98R    AB  34  2011-01-01  2011-12-31  1   1   44
1   K98R    AB  34  2012-01-01  2012-12-31  1   1   44
2   K98R    AB  34  2013-01-01  2013-08-17  1   1   44
3   K98R    AB  34  2014-01-01  2013-08-17  1   1   44
4   S33T    ES  55  2010-01-01  2010-12-31  1   0   76
5   S33T    ES  55  2011-01-01  2011-12-31  1   0   76
6   S33T    ES  55  2012-01-01  2012-03-12  1   0   76
```

Comment: Thanks, looks great. However, it seems the rows are skipping the year 2012 for the forst ID and 2011 for the second ID, any idea as to why this is happening? Also the age is not incrementing by year, could this be resolved?

Comment: Ah, there was an error in the code. Fixed it. In the for loop, the time offset was `y` when it should have been `1`.

Comment: T Hanks, Could please help with the final question regarding incrementing the of each person by row?

Comment: Sorry, i meant age increment by row, otherwise it is working great

Comment: In the for loop `for y in range...` you would add `record['Age'] = row['Age']+y-1`

Comment: Thanks I figured that one out at the end